# Latent Class Model using lclogit__Error happened

Tags: overflow, stata

I am a novice to Stata.
After conjoint analysis,
a problem occurred during Latent Class Analysis.

There are 6 conjoint properties (program, accessibility, accommodation type, facilities, privacy, price), and the levels are pro (3 levels), acc (3), stay (3), fac (3), privacy (2), price (3).
I used Stata 14.

The command syntax is like this.

```
 lclogit choice pro pro1 acc stay stay1 fac fac1 privacy price, group(gid) id(pid) ncl(2) member(gender married household disease)
```

- Dependent variable: `choice`
- Independent variables: `pro pro1 acc stay stay1 fac fac1 privacy price`
- Memberships : `gender married household disease`

An error message appears like this:

```
3,000 (group size) take 1,000 (# positives) combinations results in numeric overflow; computations cannot proceed
r(1400);

error message description is like this 
error. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . return code 1400
        numerical overflow;
        You have attempted something that, in the midst of the
        necessary calculations, has resulted in something too large
        for Stata to deal with accurately. Most commonly, this is
        an attempt to estimate a model (say with `regress`) with more
        than 2,147,483,647 effective observations. This effective
        number could be reached with far fewer observations if you
        were running a frequency-weighted model.
```

I changed different memberships and did it again and again, I got the same results.
Please advise.

Comment: The error code suggests the computation is too complex for Stata to handle. Try reducing the number of variables, properties or observations. You might need to make a decision, based on the research area, about what aspects to prioritise.

Comment: Google "combinatorial explosion", .

Comment: You had dependent variable and independent variables the wrong way round. FIxed in editing.

Comment: thank you so much~ Nick Cox. I made a mistake.